# Displaying images in python using functions and drawing them

Tags: python, zelle-graphics

```
def dice1():
dice1 = Image(Point(50, 100),'one.gif')
return dice1


def dice2():
 dice2 = Image(Point(50,100),'two.gif')
return dice2


def dice3():
 dice3 = Image(Point(50,100),'three.gif')
return dice3


def dice4():
 dice4 = Image(Point(50,100),'four.gif')
return dice4


def dice5():
 dice5 = Image(Point(50,100),'five.gif')
return dice5


def dice6():
 dice6 = Image(Point(50,100),'six.gif')
return dice6


def displaying_dice(arg1):
 if arg1 == 1:
    printed = dice1()
 elif arg1 == 2:
    printed = dice2()
 elif arg1 == 3:
    printed = dice3()
 elif arg1 == 4:
    printed = dice4()
 elif arg1 == 5:
    printed = dice5()
 elif arg1 == 6:
    printed = dice6()
 return printed
```

This question has some to do with my other questions involving Zelle Graphics in python as well.  The issue I am running into here is what I have above works for what I need it too.  I use my display_dice() function to determine what number was rolled, and then return what dice needs to be drawn, based upon that roll.  However, the instructions tell me that my display_dice() function is not supposed to return any sort of value, and this is where I am confused, because if I cannot return a value from it, how am i supposed to .draw(graph_win) the image that I need printed?   Any help is graciously appreciated.

Comment: It's hard to comment on why your instructions say what they say - we can't read them, and we don't know what the goal of the project is.  My best guess is that your instructions are telling you to have each of the dice functions (`dice1`, `dice2`, etc) directly display the image on the window rather than return the image.

Comment: See, the goal is to display the correct dice based on the roll that is rolled from a random number generator.  However, the display_dice() function is supposed to determine what dice to display, but I am not sure how to do that to draw it on the screen without a return from the display_dice function